# tcl : error when execute grep with option w

Tags: grep, tcl

I execute the following command under tclsh

```
exec sh -c "grep -w $string $file"
```

when the $string is not matched in the $file I got the following error :
child process exited abnormally

how to avoid this errror

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern is not found, grep would return 1, which exec interprets as an error and shows you the above message.

you should test the return of the grep command or add the '-q' parameter, if you want to avoid that message:

http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html

Answer (score 0):

When a subprocess exits with a non-zero exit code, `exec` generates an error. When you're dealing with a command such as `grep` where the non-zero code is also generated when things are simply not found at all.

The simplest way of dealing with this is listed in the [Tcl 8.6 `exec` manual page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.htm#M27):

```
try {
    set results [exec grep foo bar.txt]
    set status 0
} trap CHILDSTATUS {results options} {
    set status [lindex [dict get $options -errorcode] 2]
}
```

(The manual page also describes how to handle the problem in earlier versions. The code is quite a lot uglier.)

<sup>Note that you can get the same error when you `close` a pipeline containing a failing `grep`. It's the same mechanism.</sup>